# How to add checkboxes inside a column table using echo in PHP (new to coding)

Tags: php, checkbox, html-table

I'm trying to add a checkbox to the table column but can't figure out how to manage it.

**Here is my html and php code :**

```
<table  border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Select</th>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Author's Last Name</th> 
    <th>Author's First Name</th>
    <th>Format</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>ISBN Code</th>
  </tr>

<?php
  while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) )

  echo '<tr>';
  echo '<td>' . <input type="checkbox" value ="''" name="todelete[]" /> . $row['id'] . '</td><td>' . $row['title'] . '</td><td>' . $row['author_last'] . '</td><td>' . $row['author_first'] . '</td><td>' . $row['format'] . '</td><td>' . $row['price'] . '</td><td>' . $row['isbncode'] . '</td>';

   </tr>
 </table> 

?>
```

The code works fine. It shows everything in the table perfectly.

I just can't seem to type the `"input type checkbox"` in the **echo** statement. When I attempt to add the input the code stops working.

Answer (score 1):

This is the way to do it :

```
echo '<td><input type="checkbox" value ="" name="todelete[]" /> '. $row['id'] . '</td><td>' . $row['title'] . '</td><td>' . $row['author_last'] . '</td><td>' . $row['author_first'] . '</td><td>' . $row['format'] . '</td><td>' . $row['price'] . '</td><td>' . $row['isbncode'] . '</td>';
```

and also, add curly braces to your while loop `{}`.

```
<?php
  while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ) {
      echo '<td><input type="checkbox" value ="" name="todelete[]" /> '. $row['id'] . '</td><td>' . $row['title'] . '</td><td>' . $row['author_last'] . '</td><td>' . $row['author_first'] . '</td><td>' . $row['format'] . '</td><td>' . $row['price'] . '</td><td>' . $row['isbncode'] . '</td>';    
      echo '</tr>';
 }
?>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can show `input type='checkbox'` in php in *two* ways :

**CASE 1 : instead close the php tag and put the html code**

```
<?php
  while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) )
  {
    ?>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" value ="''" name="todelete[]" />
          <?php echo $row['id']; ?> </td>
      <td><?php echo $row['title']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['author_last']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['author_first']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['format']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['price']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['isbncode']; ?></td>
   </tr>
 </table> 
<?php 
}
?>
```

**CASE 2 : Put your html code in php with the of `echo`**

```
<?php
  while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ) {
      echo '<td><input type="checkbox" value ="" name="todelete[]" /> '. $row['id'] . '</td><td>' . $row['title'] . '</td><td>' . $row['author_last'] . '</td><td>' . $row['author_first'] . '</td><td>' . $row['format'] . '</td><td>' . $row['price'] . '</td><td>' . $row['isbncode'] . '</td>';    
      echo '</tr>';
 }
?>
```

Comment: i like the way of explanation

Comment: thanx @devpro, I just hope it solves the users issue, and is very clear to them

Answer (score 0):

```
$id=$row['id'];
$str = <<<EOD
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" value ='' name='todelete[]' /> $id 
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
EOD;
echo $str;

Here is more example on "Heredoc string quoting example"
http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php
```